# restart html5 animation in a given interval

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, drawing

I have a html5 canvas in which something is animated within a given time. what i'd like to do is repeat this code ("reset and restart" the drawing) in a certain interval.

```
var canvas = $("#paper")[0];
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var startX = 50;
var startY = 50;
var endX = 100;
var endY = 100;
var amount = 0;
setInterval(function() {
    amount += 0.05; // change to alter duration
    if (amount > 1) amount = 1;
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    c.strokeStyle = "black";
    c.moveTo(startX, startY);
    // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
    c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, 
             startY + (endY - startY) * amount);
    c.stroke();
}, 30);​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the setInterval function to a variable. Then you can clear it

`var interval = setInterval(function () {});`

`clearInterval(interval);`

In you case (function calle setup) you could use:

`var interval = setInterval(setup, 30);`

And when you want to clear it call:

`clearInterval(interval)`.

Comment: thank you.. i'm sorry; i'm a real novice.. i currently have a long function i'd like to repeat `function setup() { ... };` — where would i place your code?

Comment: Edited the answer to be more specific to your needs.

Comment: thanks again.. it kind of works :) .. i just placed the code above my setup function. but: now everything seems to be extremly slow, kind of lagging (eventhough i set the intervall to 1000). is this normal?